# Options for Copying Git Repo

Tags: git, github, mirror

I currently have a private git repo, and I'd like to create a public repo synced with a **single branch** of the private repo.  These are my requirements:

- don't include the entire history of all commits made to the private repo
- easily push updates from the private repo to the public copy

I tried the mirror option as outlined here, but it copied all branches and also included all previous commits.

https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have 2 upstreams set in your local directory. Sort of similar to how you'd have a forked-repo set up. here's an example

```
$ git init
$ git remote add public https://username@github.com/username/public.git
$ git remote add private https://username@github.com/private/private.git
$ git pull private the-branch
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "moving private to public"
$ git push --set-upstream public master
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thank you!  the only thing is removing the previous commits from the public repo.  do you have any advice on how to do this?  thanks again for your help!

Comment: i actually don't! I've never done that before.  maybe this will help: http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#remove_deep